# Run Time error in getche function

Tags: c, char, printf, runtime, runtime-error

I'm trying to get location of some characters in array. I use this code below, but after I entered just two characters I got run time error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()

{   
  char board [8][8]={{0}};

  char kr,kc,qr,qc,nr,nc;
  unsigned char i,j;


  for (i = 0; i < 8 ;i++)
  {
    for (j = 'A'; j <= 'H'; j++)
    {
      board[i][j] = getche();
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 8 ;i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      if (board[i][j] == 'K')
      {
        kr = i;
        kc = j;
      }
      else if (board[i][j] == 'Q')
      {
        qr = i;
        qc = j;
      }
      else if (board[i][j] == 'N')
      {
        nr = i;
        nc = j;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Q = %i %c    K = %i %c   N = %i %c",qr,qc,kr,kc,nr,nc);
  return 0;
}
```

When I change the type of `i` and `j` to `unsigned int`, program runs but prints wrong values and after print goes to run time error.

Answer (score 6):

In typical environment, `'A'` is far more than `7` (65 in ASCII code, for example)and accessing `board[i]['A']` will cause out-of-range access, which invokes *undefined behavior*. Do not access (no read nor write) out-of-range.
You must not access `board[i][8]`, neither. both of the `for` loop that use `j` as loop variable are wrong.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) /* use one of standard signatures */
{
    char board [8][8]={{0}};

    char kr=0,kc=0,qr=0,qc=0,nr=0,nc=0; /* initialize to avoid using indeterminate values */
    unsigned char i,j;


    for (i = 0; i < 8 ;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) /* correct range */
            {
                board[i][j] = getche();
            }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8 ;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) /* correct range */
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 'K')
            {
                kr = i;
                kc = j;
            }
            else if (board[i][j] == 'Q')
            {
                qr = i;
                qc = j;
            }
            else if (board[i][j] == 'N')
            {
                nr = i;
                nc = j;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Q = %i %c    K = %i %c   N = %i %c",qr,qc,kr,kc,nr,nc);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that value in range 0 to 7 are not printable characters in ASCII code, so the last `printf()` might produce what you don't want.

Comment: Good answer +1, but I still curious about what OP wants to do with `for (j = 'A'; j <= 'H'; j++)`

Answer (score 1):

OP apparently wants to use use `'A', 'B', ... 'H'` as `0,1,...7` for indexing the array `board[][]`.  Yet `'A'` has a value and it is not 0, but typically 65 - The ASCII value for the character `A`.

```
char board [8][8]={{0}};
...
for (i = 0; i < 8 ;i++) {
  for (j = 'A'; j <= 'H'; j++) {
    //       v--------------- problem
    board[i][j] = getche();
  }
}
```

Various solutions

Reasonably portable to ASCII based compilers

```
  for (j = 'A'; j <= 'H'; j++) {
    board[i][j - 'A'] = getche();
  }
```

C11 portable using compound literal - not that practical but for fun.

```
  for (j = 'A'; j <= 'H'; j++) {
    board[i][strtol((char [2]){j, '\0'}, NULL, 18)] = getche();
  }
```

or simply use 0 to 7

```
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    board[i][j] = getche();
  }
```

---

OP certainly has a 2nd problem

```
  char board [8][8]={{0}};
  ...
  for (i = 0; i < 8 ;i++) {    
    //                 9?!
    // for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j = 'A'; j <= 'H'; j++)
```

I don't know what this line is supposed to do, but initializing at the character A and then starting to initialize the array from that position doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: _doesn't seem right to me_...it is totally wrong due to `'A'` is `65` a little bit out of bound of 8 columns matrix.. ;)